# Is there a way access the promsd service created by Istio in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, istio

I'd like to access the Prometheus service run by Istio from another pod in my cluster.  On my local development environment using [Kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind), I'm able to access it at `http://prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local:9090`.  I was hoping to do the same thing on GKE, so I spun up a cluster using the Istio `addon` in GKE:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create $GCLOUD_CLUSTER_NAME \
       --addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,Istio \
       --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
       --num-nodes=4 \
       --cluster-version=latest --zone=$GCLOUD_CLUSTER_ZONE \
       --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --enable-ip-alias \
       --enable-autorepair \
       --scopes cloud-platform \
       --preemptible
```

At first, I was confused because I didn't see a `prometheus` service in the `istio-system` namespace and then I learned that they [renamed the prometheus service to promsd for Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/release-notes).  I attempted to access Prometheus at `http://promsd.istio-system.svc.cluster.local:9090/` but it didn't work.  I tried to `telnet` to it from another pod to test connectivity but I got a `Connection Refused`:

```
root@shiny-wordcloud-69684cd88-lhxc8:/# telnet promsd.istio-system.svc.cluster.local 9090
Trying 10.0.1.215...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I then saw that there are [instructions for enabling Prometheus for Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#enable_prometheus) and was pretty confused since I though Prometheus came with Istio out of the box.

My question are:

- Is there any way to access the promsd service?
- What is the purpose of the [instructions for enabling Prometheus for Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#enable_prometheus)?  Is that the correct way to access Prometheus metrics in GKE?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question I'd say that you must [expose](https://github.com/collabnix/dockerlabs/blob/master/kubernetes/cheatsheets/kubectl.md#expose) promsd service in order to be able to access it. Exposing this service means making it possible to see metrics from the cluster from the internet. So, be aware of this. To accomplish this you may execute similar command e.g.:

`kubectl expose deployment promsd --type=LoadBalancer --name=promsd`

For the second one, the [purpose of using Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/white-box-app-monitoring-for-gke-with-prometheus) depends on what kind of monitoring tool suit you best. 
And for accessing this metrics is you may use [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus#viewing_metrics) or [Graphana](https://grafana.com/).

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding between us.  I'm trying to access `promsd` from another pod within the cluster, not from the outside Internet.  I shouldn't I be able to access via [internal DNS for services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records) within the cluster?  It looks like port 9090 should be open, so I'm not sure why the connection is being refused.

Answer (score 0):

I was over your case and follow this documentation:

a) You have to enable an istio gateway and virtual service to allow configuration at envoy proxy level and then allow connection to prometheus:

Running this command and could get the forwarding:

```
$ kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l app=promsd -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 9090:9090
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9090 -> 9090
```

It's working.

This is the documentation, that I followed:

[gke-istio-telemetry-demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-istio-telemetry-demo)

And for your second question:

I found this link in the public docs from Google:
[Monitoring Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think the right command is: kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l app=promsd -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 9090:9090